# Concatenating function to string prints before the string

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

```
def capitalize(string)
  puts "#{string[0].upcase}#{string[1..-1]}"
end

puts "say few words: "
words = gets.chomp
puts "your answer is: " + capitalize(words).to_s
```

I'm expecting the output:

> say few words:
>
> your answer is: CAPITALISED INPUT

but instead I'm getting:

> say few words:
>
> CAPITALISED INPUT
>
> your answer is:

Comment: Learn the difference between __evaluating__ an expression and __printing__ a value.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "the method is printed". The first line to be printed would be: `say few words: `. I have no idea in what sense that line would be called a method.

Comment: the first and second line asks for a string input but the output (on third line) is reversed. I get as output capitalize(words).to_s + "your answer is: " and not the other way around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost correct, but you are printing something, you call a method in it, get just a string, not to print again.

```
def capitalize(string) 
  "#{string[0].upcase}#{string[1..-1]}"
end

puts "say few words: "
words = gets.chomp
puts "your answer is: " + capitalize(words)
```

Comment: The method is already returning a string, so you don't need to convert anything :)

Comment: @Horned: this code, in Ursus' answer, won't raise any errors.

Comment: i've got it, the problem was the "puts" in the method, cheers

Comment: @Horned That's right, `puts` handles actually *put*ting something onto stdout (the 'standard output' in your shell) - so you don't want to do that twice for one line. Instead, `capitalize` *returns* a string value, which you concatenate to another, and then `puts` the whole thing.